React native with expo reacts to the pressing of a button on the device
I need my background application to be able to react to a combination of buttons, for example, pressing the device's unlock button twice and based on that, generate an event in my application.
Is there a way to achieve this behavior with expo or with any react native library?
I didn't try anything since I can't find documentation about it, maybe someone had the same need and knows how to solve it.

I've never read anything about being able to make it happen as far as device buttons. But if you check the documentation for Accessibility, there's a few different ways you can access Accessibility Actions information.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/accessibility#accessibility-actions
